# Nativescript error require nativescript-background-http module

Tags: telerik, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

I'm using Telerik AppBuilder, trying to import nativescript-background-http module in my app and get error **Module "nativescript-background-http" not found**. When i'm looking for it in Properties => Dependencies, it is present in installed NPM Packages. Can i make smth with it?

Comment: You can follow the discussion in our [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nativescript/ZrtAkrleVMA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is an issue in desktop appbuilder client. It can be fixed following the next steps:

- Remove the dependencies entries from the configuration file and save
  your project, commit if necessary
- Open your Telerik Platform account
- Locate the project in the web portal and open it
- Open Properties > Dependencies
- Install the plugin(s) from the Marketplace
- Save the project
- Open the project from your preferred AppBuilder client

Hope it will be fixed in the next versions.